# How to create this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
actions(id, name)
orders(refno, po)
order_actions(order, action)
```

I'd like to obtain all the orders for which a specific action hasn't been performed. An order may or many not contain actions.

Supposing that I'd like to obtain all the orders that haven't been applied the action `13`,  so far I have something like this:

```
SELECT o.po, oa.action, 
    FROM orders AS `o`
    LEFT JOIN order_actions AS `oa` ON o.refno = oa.order
WHERE oa.action <> 13
```

That works well with orders that have no actions, but if an order has an action different than `13` the I get false positives, am I missing another join involving the `actions` table maybe a `GROUP BY` for the po or an extra `WHERE` clause?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also solve this problem with a group by and having clause:

```
SELECT o.refno, o.po
FROM orders AS `o` LEFT JOIN
     order_actions `oa`
     ON o.refno = oa.order
group by o.refno, o.po
having max(case when oa.action = 13 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you want to keep track of all actions on such orders, you can use group_concat:

```
SELECT o.refno, o.po,
       group_concat(cast(ao.action) separator ', ') as AllOtherActions
FROM orders AS `o` LEFT JOIN
     order_actions `oa`
     ON o.refno = oa.order
group by o.refno, o.po
having max(case when oa.action = 13 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: that seems jolly complicated. Interesting approach though.

Comment: @JohnBingham . . . It depends on how you look at it.  To me, the use of a having clause to filter members of a set doesn't seem complicated at all.  In fact, it seems simpler than a correlated subquery.

Comment: Completely agree, your query was what I had in mind but didn't know how to express it in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT o.po, oa.action
FROM orders AS `o`
     LEFT JOIN order_actions AS `oa` ON o.refno = oa.order
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM order_actions tmp 
  WHERE oa.order = tmp.order 
    AND tmp.action = '13'
)
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f5d1/2)** (sqlfiddle).

Comment: Why the `1` value, would you mind explaining a bit I tried the query and it takes a long time, it has not finished execution. I have about 2.3k orders and 5k order actions.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `action` column? Is `order` a primary key in `order_actions`? `1` is just so that the `SELECT` is not empty, it could be an `"X"`, or any column `tmp.order`, since we are not interested in the result of that sub-select, only if it returns or not rows for the `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: I created the index and indeed the `orders(id)` is a primary key still it takes forever. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be this:

```
select o.po
from orders as 'o'
    left join (
        select order from order_actions where [action] = @Action
        ) AS `oa` on o.refno = oa.order
where oa.order is null
```

This doesnt return action numbers for orders you select, but you've stated that you're just looking for the orders that havent had an action, which I reference here as @Action